# Installed uWSGI from cygwin but unable to find from installed package

Tags: python, django, cygwin, uwsgi

I am new to Django framework. I need to develop a chat function in my app. I am required to install uWSGI as websocket. As I am using Windows so I will install it using cygwin. I followed the instruction from some of the website and had successfully installed it ($ python3 setup.py install).
However, I couldn't find it in my python project. I have tried to install it in the **python project site-packages** and also the **django python site-packages**. Yet, I still couldn't find it in my installed packages. May I know what have done wrong or misunderstood the concept?

[Cmd of cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUAZb.png)

Comment: how you are checking the installed packages ?

Comment: I check from the setting>project>project Interpreter. And i couldn't import uWSGI as well